# Django celery tasks number limit issue

Tags: python, django, multithreading, celery, worker

I have problem run celery workers to execute same task multiple times in parallel.

I ran 3 workers and set --concurrency to 2 for all workers.

But it only executes 3 tasks over all 3 workers.

I hope to run about 10 workers.

```
celery -A my_app worker -l info  -c 2 -n worker1
celery -A my_app worker -l info  -c 2 -n worker2
celery -A my_app worker -l info  -c 2 -n worker3
```

Please help me whether I can run more than 3 tasks at a time.

Comment: You can check ```autoscale``` option in celery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using **max-tasks-per-child** argument.

Here is my solution.

```
celery -A my_app worker -l info -c 10 --max-tasks-per-child 10 -n worker1
```

After running this, it can execute 10 same tasks at a time in parallel.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: The `--max-tasks-per-child` setting has nothing to do with parallel execution of tasks. It specifies how many tasks a child process executes before it is killed and replaced with a new process. The option `-c 10` is what specifies the number of child processes, and hence the number of parallel tasks that can run.